# user command line not using stdin and stdout

Tags: linux, io, terminal

My program is invoked by another process, and communicates with it via stdin and stdout.  I want to interact with my program via a command line interface, but obviously the usual method of just running it in a terminal doesn't work.  I'm looking for the simplest possible way of achieving this.

My program is currently written in Lua, but might become C or something else.  Running under GNU/Linux, but something simple that works under Windows as well would be great.

Comment: Why dont you use standard ipc interfaces like shared memory/unix sockets or pipes.

Comment: Did you read a book like http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ to have broad knowledge of most IPC ?

Comment: I ended up using TCP sockets, which was more hassle than I wanted but less than I expected.  Got my program to launch a terminal running telnet to the socket, so pretty smooth to use.  Thanks all.

Comment: You could use `AF_UNIX` sockets, or named pipes (`mkfifo`)